# overide own controler / model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oop, codeigniter-3

Is there a way to override all controllers folder by an other folder?

**example:**

Let say I have a function  `customer/export`
that **suppose** to `"application/controller/customers" - function export()`

I would like it to check first if there is a file in `"application/overrideController/customers" - function export()`

if method exists there, use the method in `"overrideController"` folder.

**if not, use the normal controler folder**

I would like to do it also for views and models if possible.

thanks :)

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: [Hooks - Extending the Framework Core](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html?highlight=extending#hooks-extending-the-framework-core)

Comment: Iv'e seen this, dont think its good for me (or maybe not understood it good enough).
I want to override the controller that I myself wrote (in application/controller folder), not the core hooks.

also, I prefer not using any default dir of codeigniter.